# Photo Marker Inside Circle in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, customization, leaflet, marker

I am making map with Leaflet. I want the default marker to be replaced with the Image of mine, so I want Image Marker. The Image Marker should be inside the Circle and the outline of the Circle should be Green.Plus it should have a tail, something like this (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4sqjpR8WikRb0NEeXk1Y3lSZjQ/view). I want circle marker with the triangle like in its tail to represent the position.
 How can I do that with CSS or any other tricks.

I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

To put your own image, you want to use the icon option of the marker (see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-icon)

To have it round, you just tweak the css of the image

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

For the color, you add a border to the image

```
border-color: green;
```

For an example, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/pod1L68g/)

Comment: I edited the question. Please see the above link and suggest me the css or svg or other way.